# Critical sections with multicore processors

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, cpu-architecture

With a single-core processor, where all your threads are run from the one single CPU, the idea of implementing a critical section using an atomic test-and-set operation on some mutex (or semaphore or etc) in memory seems straightforward enough; because your processor is executing a test-and-set from one spot in your program, it necessarily can't be doing one from another spot in your program disguised as some other thread.

But what happens when you do actually have more than one physical processor? It seems that simple instruction level atomicity wouldn't be sufficient, b/c with two processors potentially executing their test-and-set operations at the same time, what you really need to maintain atomicity on is access to the shared memory location of the mutex. (And if the shared memory location is loaded into cache, there's the whole cache consistency thing to deal with, too..)

This seems like it would incur far more overhead than the single core case, so here's the meat of the question: How much worse is it? Is it worse? Do we just live with it? Or sidestep it by enforcing a policy that all threads within a process group have to live on the same physical core?

Comment: Isnt test-and-set guaranteed to be atomic across multiple CPU's already?

Comment: test and set has consensus number only 2.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Multi-core/SMP systems are not just several CPUs glued together. There's explicit support for doing things in parallel. All the synchronization primitives are implemented with the help of hardware along the lines of [atomic CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap). The instruction either locks the bus shared by CPUs and memory controller (and devices that do DMA) and updates the memory, or just updates the memory relying on [cache snooping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_snooping). This in turn causes [cache coherency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherency) algorithm to kick in forcing all involved parties to flush their caches.
Disclaimer - this is very basic description, there are more interesting things here like virtual vs. physical caches, cache write-back policies, memory models, fences, etc. etc.

If you want to know more about how OS might use these hardware facilities - here's [an excellent book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633388) on the subject.

Comment: great answer, but also how costly is this atomic CAS on a modern multi-core and multi-processor systems? For applications that'll have to use it a lot, does the cost at some point necessitate having to have two separate machines, or is the cost of the atomic CAS negligible compared to other things?

Comment: Compared to what other things? Like transferring data over the network? Path down and then up the TCP/IP stack involves multiple synchronization points, which in turn rely on said atomic ops.

Answer (score 6):

The vendor of multi-core cpus has to take care that the different cores coordinate themselves when executing instructions which guarantee atomic memory access.

On intel chips for instance you have the 'cmpxchg' instruction. It compares the value stored at a memory location to an expected value and exchanges it for the new value if the two match. If you precede it with the 'lock' instruction, it is guaranteed to be atomic with respect to all cores.

Answer (score 3):

You would need a test-and-set that forces the processor to notify all the other cores of the operation so that they are aware. Yes, that introduces an overhead and you have to live with it. It's a reason to design multithreaded applications in such a way that they don't wait for synchronization primitives too often.

Answer (score 3):

> Or sidestep it by enforcing a policy that all threads within a process group have to live on the same physical core?

That would cancel the whole point of multithreading. When you are using a lock, semaphore, or other syncronization techniques, you are relying on OS to make sure that these operations are interlocked, no matter how many cores you are using.

The time to switch to a different thread after a lock has been released is mostly determined by the cost of a context switch. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304752/how-to-estimate-the-thread-context-switching-overhead) SO thread deals with the context switching overhead, so you might want to check that.

There are some other interesting threads also:

- [What are the differences between various threading synchronization options in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301160/what-are-the-differences-between-various-threading-synchronization-options-in-c)
- [Threading best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660621/threading-best-practices)

You should read this MSDN article also: [Understanding the Impact of Low-Lock Techniques in Multithreaded Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163715.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Memory accesses are handled by the memory controller which should take care of multi-core issues, i.e. it shouldn't allow simultaneous access to same addresses (probably handled either by memory page or memory line basis). So you can use a flag to indicate whether another processor is updating the memory contents of some block (this to avoid a type of dirty read where part of the record is updated, but not all).

A more elegant solution is to use a HW semaphore block if the processor has such a feature. A HW semaphore is a simple queue which could be of size no_of_cores -1. This is how it is in TI's 6487/8 processor. You can either query the semaphore directly (and loop until it is released) or do an indirect query which will result in an interrupt once your core gets the resource. The requests are queued and served in the order they were made. A semaphore query is an atomic operation.

Cache consistency is another issue and you might need to do cache writebacks and refreshes in some cases. But this is a very cache implementation specific thing. With 6487/8 we needed to do that on a few operations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on what type of computers you have laying around the house, do the following: Write a simple multithreaded application. Run this application on a single core (Pentium 4 or Core Solo) and then run it on a multicore processor (Core 2 Duo or similar) and see how big the speed up is.

Granted these are unfair comparisons since Pentium 4 and Core Solo are much slower regardless of cores than a Core 2 Duo. Maybe compare between a Core 2 Duo and a Core 2 Quad with an application that can use 4 or more threads.

You raise a number of valid points. Muliple processors introduce a lot of headache and overhead. However, we just have to live with them, because the speed boost of parallelism can far outweigh them, if the critical sections are made long enough.

As for your final suggestion about having all threads on the same physical core, that completely defeats the point of a multi-core computer!