# How to save data to MongoDB by pipeline when using multi spiders in Scrapy?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, scrapy, pipeline

There are 2 spiders that I use to get data from webpage, and I use `Crawler Process()` to run them at the same time.
The spiders' code:

```
class GDSpider(Spider):
name = "GenDis"
allowed_domains = ["gold.jgi.doe.gov"]
base_url ="https://gold.jgi.doe.gov/projects"
stmp = []
term = "man"
for i in range(1, 1000):
    url = "https://gold.jgi.doe.gov/projects?page="+ str(i) +"&Project.Project+Name="+ term+ "&count=25"
    stmp.append(url)

start_urls = stmp

def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//tr[@class="odd"]|//tr[@class="even"]')

    for site in sites:
        item = GenDis()
        item['Id'] = site.xpath('td/a/text()').extract()
        item['Link'] = site.xpath('td/a/@href').extract()
        item['Name'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract())
        item['Status'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[3]/text()').extract())
        item['Add_Date'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract())
        yield item



class EPGD_spider(Spider):
    name = "EPGD"
    allowed_domains = ["epgd.biosino.org"]
    term = "man"
    start_urls = ["http://epgd.biosino.org/EPGD/search/textsearch.jsp?textquery="+term+"&submit=Feeling+Lucky"]
    MONGODB_DB = name + "_" + term
    MONGODB_COLLECTION = name + "_" + term

def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//tr[@class="odd"]|//tr[@class="even"]')
    url_list = []
    base_url = "http://epgd.biosino.org/EPGD"

    for site in sites:
        item = EPGD()
        item['genID'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[1]/a/text()').extract())
        item['genID_url'] = base_url+map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[1]/a/@href').extract())[0][2:]
        item['taxID'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[2]/a/text()').extract())
        item['taxID_url'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[2]/a/@href').extract())
        item['familyID'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[3]/a/text()').extract())
        item['familyID_url'] = base_url+map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[3]/a/@href').extract())[0][2:]
        item['chromosome'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract())
        item['symbol'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[5]/text()').extract())
        item['description'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[6]/text()').extract())
        yield item

    sel_tmp = Selector(response)
    link = sel_tmp.xpath('//span[@id="quickPage"]')

    for site in link:
        url_list.append(site.xpath('a/@href').extract())

    for i in range(len(url_list[0])):
        if cmp(url_list[0][i], "#") == 0:
            if i+1 < len(url_list[0]):
                print url_list[0][i+1]
                actual_url = "http://epgd.biosino.org/EPGD/search/"+ url_list[0][i+1]
                yield Request(actual_url, callback=self.parse)
                break
            else:
                print "The index is out of range!"

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(EPGD_spider)
process.crawl(GDSpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until all crawling jobs are finished
```

I want to save the data to MongoDB database. Here is my pipeline code:

```
class EPGD_pipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        connection = pymongo.MongoClient(
            settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
            settings['MONGODB_PORT']
        )
        db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        valid = True
        for data in item:
            if not data:
                valid = False
                raise DropItem("Missing {0}!".format(data))
        if valid:
            self.collection.insert(dict(item))
            log.msg("Item wrote to MongoDB database {}, collection {}, at host {}, port {}".format(
            settings['MONGODB_DB'],
            settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION'],
            settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
            settings['MONGODB_PORT']))
        return item
```

It works correctly when I use one spider at one time. But when I run them at the same time, it seems that the pipeline doesn't work any more. Neither database nor collections have been set up.
I've seen the `CrawlerProcess()` part of Scrapy document many times, but it doesn't mention about the pipeline things. So can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you want to store the item in same db and collection or different db and collection ?

Comment: different db and collections,do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should fix the problem:

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(EPGD_spider)
process.crawl(GDSpider)
process.start()
```

You will also likely need to refactor your spider code to open a connection for each spider (this example is using "Bonus Tip 2" below):

```
# In your pipeline

class EPGD_pipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.collections = {
            spider_name: self.setup_db_connection(dj_mongo_database_url.parse(url))
            for spider_name, url in settings['MONGODB_PIPELINE_SETTINGS'].iterItems()
        )
    }

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        collection = self.collections[spider.name]
        ...


# In settings.py

MONGODB_PIPELINE_SETTINGS = {
    "GenDis": "mongodb://myhost:29297/test_db/collection",
    "EPGD": "mongodb://myhost:29297/test_db/collection2",
}
```

Bonus Tip 1: Use [txmongo](https://github.com/twisted/txmongo) instead of pymongo, otherwise you'll be getting potentially very bad performance (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557521/what-exactly-is-wrong-with-using-pymongo-in-twisted)).

Bonus Tip 2: All those settings get difficult to manage. Consider using something like [django-mongo-database-url](https://github.com/RyanBalfanz/django-mongo-database-url/blob/develop/test_dj_mongo_database_url.py) to "pack" them all in a single URL and keep them more manage-able (would be more clean if [collection was also in the URL](https://github.com/RyanBalfanz/django-mongo-database-url/pull/2)).

Bonus Tip 3: You likely do way too many writes/transactions. If the use-case allows, save results to `.jl` file(s) and use [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) to bulk-import on crawl finish. Here's how to do it in more detail.

Assuming a project named `tutorial` and a spider named `example` that creates 100 items, you create an extension in `tutorial/extensions.py`:

```
import logging
import subprocess

from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exceptions import NotConfigured

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class MyBulkExtension(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler)

    def __init__(self, crawler):
        settings = crawler.settings

        self._feed_uri = settings.get('FEED_URI', None)
        if self._feed_uri is None:
            raise NotConfigured('Missing FEED_URI')
        self._db = settings.get('BULK_MONGO_DB', None)
        if self._db is None:
            raise NotConfigured('Missing BULK_MONGO_DB')
        self._collection = settings.get('BULK_MONGO_COLLECTION', None)
        if self._collection is None:
            raise NotConfigured('Missing BULK_MONGO_COLLECTION')

        crawler.signals.connect(self._closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)

    def _closed(self, spider, reason, signal, sender):
        logger.info("writting file %s to db %s, colleciton %s" %
                    (self._feed_uri, self._db, self._collection))
        command = ("mongoimport --db %s --collection %s --drop --file %s" %
                   (self._db, self._collection, self._feed_uri))

        p = subprocess.Popen(command.split())
        p.communicate()

        logger.info('Import done')
```

On your `tutorial/settings.py`, you activate the extension and set the two settings:

```
EXTENSIONS = {
    'tutorial.extensions.MyBulkExtension': 500
}

BULK_MONGO_DB = "test"
BULK_MONGO_COLLECTION = "foobar"
```

You can then run your crawl like this:

```
$ scrapy crawl -L INFO example -o foobar.jl
...
[tutorial.extensions] INFO: writting file foobar.jl to db test, colleciton foobar
connected to: 127.0.0.1
dropping: test.foobar
check 9 100
imported 100 objects
[tutorial.extensions] INFO: Import done
...
```

Comment: You mean that I've do too many writes,and I should see `mongoimport ` to write the data to mongodb at one time?

Comment: Each time you do a single write, mongo (and every other DB) goes through the process of acquiring some locks. This makes the write more expensive. By using bulk import, the locks are acquired only once, typically several optimizations at db-level get enabled and your import is way more efficient. With your original code you do writes for each item. If your use case allows you to do bulk import at the end of the crawl i.e. your crawl takes relatively short time, then prefer to do bulk import VS individual inserts.

Comment: Thank you! I'll get more thing about bulk!

Comment: @Coding_Rabbit - Glad. I updated the answer to include exactly how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I have one more question that if the name of database and collections that I want to insert data in hasn't been set before scrapy.  For example : I want the name of the database and collections to be set as `name + term `,just if the name is `EPGD` and the term is `man`, I want the name of database and collections are `EPGD man`.How to do this?

Comment: If you do this, you will have to do it on each subsequent processing stage. You will need to have scripts that know which terms exist, form database/collection names etc. Do you need this hassle? Did you run out of the processing capabilities of your DB and need to get into the "multiple small databases" domain? Unless this is true, you are better off adding two extra fields in your `Item`s for 'name' and 'term' and then use mongodb's indices to accelerate any accesses. I can see that this was your original implementation, but, in general, people consciously avoid having 100's of collections.

Comment: That said - if you really need to do that there are options. You could add the `name-term` info at each item. Then at the end, instead of calling directly `mongoimport` you could call a bash script that segments the data however you like. Also if you're running separate crawls for each spider, then you know what you're scraping while you're running `scrapy crawl`. You could do for example: `scrapy crawl -o EPGD_man_feed.jl` and then on the pipeline, in the `_closed()` function do: `self._db, self._collection, _ = self._feed_url.split('_')`. You can then remove those settings from `__init__ `.

Comment: So add attribute `name` and `term` is a better choice ? I just consider that it'll be easier to subsequent search operations. For example : next time I want to get information about `man` in `EPGD`, I can get it from my mongodb instead of scrawling it again, so I guess if the collections and database's name is related what I search for may be more convenient,I can just find whether there is data in mongodb by the name.Am I right? Or is there are any other good options to do this?

Comment: Yes, adding attribute is certainly the way to go. Then you do a `db.items.find( { "name": "EPGD", "term": "man" } )` in mongo and you get the records.  `db.items.find( { "name": "EPGD", "term": "man" } ).count()` will give you the number or records.